# HP DL20 Gen 9 + Ubuntu 16.04 = LOM Error + Unclaimed Network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, hp

I previously have HP DL20 Gen9 server working well with Ubuntu 16.04 on LOM  (Lan On Motherboard) 1
and then suddenly LOM 1 seems have trouble on networking

[LOM 1 tes result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqblF.jpg)

[Lom 1 tes log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW659.jpg)

so I change networking to LOM 2
but it is not last long, the LOM 2 also have trouble on networking

I tried to reset bios by plug out and plug in cmos battery (I thought it would work)

[reset bios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUpmm.jpg)

but it's getting worse, the server didn't detect all LOM

login to ubuntu and check the error result :

[bios corrupted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6g9S.jpg)

and do : lshw -C network, the result is UNCLAIMED mark

[unclaimed network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb3ow.jpg)

I am sorry cannot paste the result in text because the server still cannot connect to the network, only photos :(

any help is going to be appreciated

thank you